# Is there a limited amount of integer solutions to $a^{4}+b^{3}=c^{2}$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

So far I have found $a=1 , b=2 , c=3$. Are there any other whole number solutions to this equation?

Comment: For any $d \in \Bbb{N}$, $a= d^3, b = 2d^4, c = 3d^6$ is a solution.

Comment: Why does that look like fermat's theorem

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions with $b=0$

Comment: Look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a%5E4%2Bb%5E3-c%5E2%3D0+over+integers).

Answer (score 6):

This is the generalised Fermat equation
$$
x^p+y^q=z^r
$$
for $(p,q,r)=(3,4,2)$, where we are in the spherical case
$$
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{13}{12}>1.
$$
There we have infinitely many integer solutions, see for example [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=Fj2lDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=x%5E3%2By%5E4%3Dz%5E2+generalized++fermat+spherical+case&source=bl&ots=tc7Bgv-w-0&sig=ACfU3U34L4wE6HOJj3S8pFI4n03TcycJig&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisobDb06zqAhUNr4sKHYiDAvsQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=x%5E3%2By%5E4%3Dz%5E2%20generalized%20%20fermat%20spherical%20case&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a^2$ is a triangle number (it is well-known that there are an infinite number of squares that are also triangular - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number)).  Then:

$$a^2 = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$

Putting $b=x+1$ and rearranging:

$$2a^2=b^2-b$$

Putting $c=a^2+b$:

$$c^2-a^4=(a^2+b)^2-a^4=a^4+2a^2b+b^2-a^4=(b^2-b)b+b^2=b^3$$

Hence $a^4+b^3=c^2$, the smallest non-trivial examples being $1^4+2^3=3^2$ and $6^4+9^3=45^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Equation, $(a^4+b^3=c^2)$ has parameteric solution:

$a=(pqw^3)$

$b=(2q^2w^3)$

$c=(p^2q^2w^4+2q^2w^5)$

$p=4k-3$

$q=3k-2$

$w=2k^2-1$

For, $k=-1$

$(a,b,c)=(35,50,1275)$

$35^4+50^3=1275^2$

Answer (score 0):

$a^4+b^3=c^2$

$a=t^2(u-1)v$

$b=t^3(v^2)$

$c=t^4uv^2(3u-2)$

Where, $t=2u^2-1$

$v=(2u-1)$

For u=2, we have:

$147^4+3087^3=(172872)^2$